# How to assign $smarty object to to php function?

Tags: php, function, smarty

**index.php**

```
require_once('smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$Smarty = new Smarty();

function do_something() {
    global $Smarty; 
        echo "where is smarty?"

    var_dump($Smarty); 
    $ObjSmarty->assign("teams_list", $teams_list);
}
get_active_teams();
```

Nothing dumps and error assigning...

```
require_once('smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$Smarty = new Smarty();

function do_something() {
    global $Smarty; 
        echo "where is smarty?"

    var_dump($GLOBALS); 
    var_dump($GLOBALS["Smarty"]); 
}
get_active_teams();
```

dump of globals shows Smarty and when i dump $globals["smarty"] nothing. Whats going on.

I don't have class is that the problem?

How can i assign to loaded smarty object inside php function without using declaring class?

Comment: You call it $Smarty and $ObjSmarty in your first example - is that a typo or actually in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Did you call the do_something function somewhere?
Perhaps you can do this:

```
function do_something($Smarty) {
    // ... Do something with smarty here...
}
do_something($Smarty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Global variables is not a very good idea, why not pass $Smarty as a function parameter?

```
function foo($smarty) {
    var_dump($smarty);
}

foo($smarty);
```